# ActiveSkin GDI Leak

Tags: gdi, memory-leaks, skin

[ActiveSkin](http://www.softshape.com/) used in all forms of our application, which has been originally developed in VB6 and later migrated into VB.NET.
This unmanaged code wrapped into Interop, and declared in our class SkinForm, which is inherited by all forms in the our application.

Now we have the following code in the method OnFormClosing in our class:

```
MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
If Not ActiveSkin Is Nothing AndAlso Me.Controls.Contains(ActiveSkin) Then
    Me.Controls.Remove(ActiveSkin)
End If
ActiveSkin = Nothing
```

Where ActiveSkin - it is a wrapper for SkinForm class from ActiveSkin library.

The GDI leak occurs after each form closing.

If we add the following code:

```
ActiveSkin.Dispose()
```

after removing it from the controls collection. Leak disappears. But at the first close of any form, we get the following message (only once during the application execution):

“*Warning! This application was created with trial version of ActiveSkin control. 
You can register ActiveSkin here: http://www.softshape.com/activeskin*”.

Of course we have a license for library .

Do you have any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Install Deleaker and debug, debug, debug...